# Sorting a Pytorch Tensor by Trace

Tags: sorting, pytorch, vectorization, tensor

I have a (100,64,22,3,3) shaped pytorch tensor, and I would like to sort along axis=0 by the trace of the (3,3) components. The code I have below works, but it is very slow due to the for loops. Is there a way to vectorize the operation to speed it up?

```
x=torch.rand(100,64,22,3,3)
x_sorted=torch.zeros((x.shape[0],x.shape[1],x.shape[2],x.shape[3],x.shape[4]))
            for i in range(x.shape[0]):
              #compute tensorized trace
              trace=new=torch.diagonal(x[i], dim1=-2, dim2=-1).sum(-1) 
              #Sort the trace
              trace_values,trace_ind=torch.sort(trace,dim=0,descending=True)
              for j in range(x_sorted.shape[1]):
                for k in range(x_sorted.shape[2]):
                  x_sorted[i,j,k]=x[i,trace_ind[j,k],k]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
tensor = torch.tensor(np.random.rand(100,64, 3, 3))

orders = torch.argsort(torch.einsum('ijkk->ijk', tensor).sum(-1), axis=0)
orders.shape

tensor[orders, torch.arange(s.shape[1])[None, :]]
```

Comment: In the last line, should s.shape[1] be orders.shape[1]. This throws a shape mismatch error.